# Chinese text not encoded correctly in web service after sent from PDF

Tags: itext

We have a problem that when simplified chinese words are sent from PDF to web service that 
after the message is encoded, the chinese words are converted to "messy" chinese words.
We are using the gb2312 encoding in the web service and it works for some messages but now there is 1 case where it doesn't.

For example :

in PDF= 市区 
After encoding= 巗嬫

Comment: I am assuming that you are not talking about a PDF with embedded Chinese glyphs, but about text sent from a PDF to a web service. In that case, this is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604171/data-encoding-when-submitting-a-pdf-form-using-acroform-technology The only way to make sure that you can predict the encoding is by adding JavaScript to the PDF so that the encoding is defined using the `cCharset` parameter.