# Decoding String from UTF-8 to Windows1256

Tags: php, utf-8, utf

I have the code below, which tries to convert a string from UTF to CP1256. I want to decode the string to arabic, and the page encryption is fixed to UTF8

```
<?php 

$string = "ãÍãÏ Úæäí ãÍãæÏ Úáí";
$string = iconv("UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE",     $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Alastair McCormack I want the string to be showed in arabic, which is محمد عوني محمود علي

Comment: What's the encoding of your source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$strings = "ãÍãÏ Úæäí ãÍãæÏ Úáí";

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'nl_NL.UTF-8');

$convert = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $strings);

echo var_dump($convert);
```

Answer (score 2):

So your Arabic text, has been encoded in Windows-1256 and then incorrectly encoded to Windows-1252.

If your source file is UTF-8 encoded, the answer is:

```
<?php

$string = "ãÍãÏ Úæäí ãÍãæÏ Úáí";
$string = iconv("UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $string);
# $string is now back to its 1256 encoding. Encode to UTF-8 for web page
$string = iconv("Windows-1256//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

If your source file is "windows-1252" encoded, then you must use:

```
<?php

$string = "ãÍãÏ Úæäí ãÍãæÏ Úáí";
# Interperate windows-1252 string as if it were windows-1256. Encode to UTF-8 for web page
$string = iconv("Windows-1256//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $string);

echo $string;

?>
```

If you `$string` actually comes from a database or file, then you have to determine the encoding of the source before applying any conversion.

Comment: Than  you very much, you're code worked like a charm for few minutes, then somehow it stopped working, the real example I am working on can be found in this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405245/arabic-pdf-form-to-php-to-mysql-unicode-decoding) and if you want a copy of the PDF file, I can upload it.