# PDF does not post Marathi data properly to server

Tags: pdf, go

I have writable PDF file. There is submit button on PDF. But after submitting data marathi language data is not getting sent properly to  the server. I'm using golang server. Some dot dot characters are getting posted on server. I'm recieving this data in form-value format on server. Please help me out to get the solution.

```
txtRequesterName := c.FormValue("txtRequesterName")
```

output=>

```
// .... indicates marathi text which is not rendered
Requester Name:  ... .... .......... Important .....
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as an iText question? I don't see any mention of iText. Note that there was a flaw in ISO 32000-1: it wasn't possible to define an encoding when posting content through an AcroForm field. As a member of the ISO committee for PDF, I fixed this in ISO 32000-2 (aka PDF 2.0), but there are very few tools that already support PDF 2.0. This question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604171

Comment: which version of adobe acrobat pro supports PDF 2.0 ?

Comment: That's a question for Adobe.